# How to use dotnet watch with a Blazor Hosted?

Tags: .net, blazor

How to use `dotnet watch` with a Blazor WASM Hosted App ?

If I use it in the Client Project, the app won't work.
If I use it in the Server Project, the app starts ok, but it won't detect changes made to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the project folder and use the following command to start the blazor web assembly project:

```
dotnet watch run
```

The application will open in your browser.  You may begin modifying the application, but you will not see the changes until you Save.  When you save, the browser hosting the app will refresh with your changes.

Comment: This way i can only start one project. The blazor hosted app has two projects. Server and Client . If i start it in the client project, it won't work and if i start it in the server project, i can't attach the debugger to the client.

Comment: This answer is not good. A hosted Blazor WASM contains 3 projects. The Server, the Client and the Shared. The one to launch is the Server, which serves the Client (the WASM) as a view containing the whole SPA.

dotnet watch run in Server won't detect changes in Client.